# Dual Boot Ubuntu Alongside Loopback Device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, mount

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my new Dell XPS-15 2-in-1 which has Windows 10 on it. The problem is that the Ubuntu installer won't recognize the windows file system so I can't partition the disk to install it. I think the windows files are stored as a loopback device, or otherwise lofi (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device). I don't really know what this means. I think it's got something to do with the windows file system not being mounted in a way that ubuntu recognizes. The windows file system is NTFS.

How do I get the ubuntu installer to recognize the windows file system so I can partition the machine? I think I need to mount in some way but I'm not sure.

When I run `sudo fdisk -l` I see /dev/loop0 thru /dev/loop6 and a single /dev/sda. I think /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 are running from the USB stick that ubuntu is running off of, but I'm not sure.

pls send help <3

Comment: From Live Ubuntu UFD, what is the output with `sudo parted -l` (please edit your question).

Comment: Have you followed all the steps here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi And with Dell updated UEFI, SSD firmware if SSD and changed to AHCI from RAID in UEFI settings?